# How can I get a list of followers of a twitter account

Tags: api, rest, twitter

I'm trying to get a list of the accounts being followed by https://twitter.com/verified

how can I do this?

when I try to use the api I get this

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}
```

I have a developer key but I dont know if I had to paste it in the URL?
please help.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to obtain a access token before requesting followers.

As specified by the REST API you are required to be authenticated before making the request.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/followers/ids

The options of getting authentication here listed here:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/obtaining-access-tokens

Comment: I have access token, dont know what to do with it lol, can I append it to the url as a parameter?

Comment: You need to include the authorisation information in your request. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request

Comment: I figured out how to use it but that link is to get a list of users following user X, I want a list of users being followed by user X is it possible?

Comment: You can get the people subscribed. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/lists/subscribers